# Creating own simple markdown in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I would like to introduce a markdown-type feature in my Angularjs app but I don't won't to make use of (or offer) the full set of commands that Markdown introduces. I would like just a few basic features that make use of curly braces to indicate special content.

For example: `{ https://google.com }` would become `<a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a>` and be shown as a link in a preview pane.

I've watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKJDHnXaKTY) to give me some ideas but it makes use of Showdown which I don't really want to use.

Could anyone give me any pointers on this? I assume a directive would be the way to go here but will I need to make use of Regular Expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a parser.

Something like this might give you a start:

Say you want to transform fractions: 1/2 will be <sup>1</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>

```
 /**
 * Usage finds {#}|{#} and converts to math notation
 **/ 
 function transformFracs() {
 //Grab digits with in {} recording only the numbers
 var regex = /{(\d+)}\|{(\d+)}/;
 //Cache for performance!
 var div = $(this);
 //Replace using html fraction notaion
 var afterReplace = div.html().replace(regex,
     "<sup>$1</sup>" +
     "&frasl;" +
     "<sub>$2</sub>")
 //Replace content of original div
 div.html(afterReplace);
 }
$(".editable").blur(transformFracs);
```

I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9B4f3/6/) will give somewhat of a start

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive and modify the outer html inside the compile function.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8qL0lKCkhuTqrJwiSpiP?p=preview)

```
app.directive('markDown', function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  replace: true,
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  },
  compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {

    tElement[0].outerHTML = tElement[0].innerText + "<a href='#'>Go crazy</a>";
    console.log(tElement);

   }
 };
});
```